# Few days before Facing some error in next two Album (It is doing some weird stuff )

Tags: javascript, html, css

some days back I found an very good code for album  and its also suit to my program but now when i'm using it i'm having some errors ..

errors is like when i open it do some thing really weird like i'm on the second tab and clicking next photo button but instead of changing this album photos its is changing previous album photos .as well as the first album is not moving it always sowing up ....

I know it is difficult to visualize I request you to open this code on your local editor .....

I'm a really depress please help...............

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Shahmir's CV </title>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/cv.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <mata charaset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <mata http-equiv="refresh" content="1"></mata>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cv.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
    <!-- <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a54d2cbf95.js"></script> -->
</head>



<style>
  html {
    /* scroll-behavior: smooth; */
  }
  
  body {}
  
  #home {
    background-image: url(images/background2.png);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    /*           i use vh unit becouse to make it fit in the screen               */
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /**/
    /* filter:  grayscale(50%) ; */
  }
  /***   Album  ***/
  
  ul {
    margin-top: 90px;
  }
  
  .nav-pills>li.active>a,
  .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus,
  .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .slider {
    width: 90vmin;
    height: 90vmin;
    -webkit-perspective: 100vmin;
    perspective: 100vmin;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: top center;
    perspective-origin: top center;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .slider__item {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    /* left: 10%; */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 15vmin;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.18s ease;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.18s ease;
    transition: transform 0.18s ease;
    transition: transform 0.18s ease, -webkit-transform 0.18s ease;
  }
  
  .slider__item:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0vmin);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0vmin);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    z-index: 7;
  }
  
  .slider__item:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -15vmin);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, -15vmin);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
    z-index: 6;
  }
  
  .slider__item:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -30vmin);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, -30vmin);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  
  .slider__item:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -45vmin);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, -45vmin);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
    z-index: 4;
  }
  
  .slider__item:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -60vmin);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, -60vmin);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  
  .slider__item:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -75vmin);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, -75vmin);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .slider__item:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -90vmin);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, -90vmin);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .slider__item:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, -105vmin);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, -105vmin);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
    transition-delay: 0.35s;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  
  .slider__image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    background-color: #999;
    border: 1.5vmin solid rgb(66, 65, 65);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 0vmin 0vmin 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), 1px 1vmin 2vmin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease, -webkit-transform 0.18s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease, -webkit-transform 0.18s ease;
    transition: transform 0.18s ease, opacity 0.2s ease;
    transition: transform 0.18s ease, opacity 0.2s ease, -webkit-transform 0.18s ease;
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
  }
  
  .slider__caption {
    /* height: 20%; */
    font-size: 150%;
    margin-top: -2%;
    /* top:-42px; */
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .slider__btn {
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* bottom: 0; */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* top: 88%;  */
    width: 9vmin;
    height: 9vmin;
    margin: 2vmin auto;
    border-right: 2vmin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    border-bottom: 2vmin solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(10vmin) rotateX(-30deg) rotateZ(45deg);
    transform: perspective(10vmin) rotateX(-30deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  }
  
  .slider__btn:active {
    border-right-color: #dd6;
    border-bottom-color: #dd6;
  }
  
  .section-title2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /* margin-top: 50PX; */
    padding-top: 79px;
  }
</style>

<BODY>





  <h5 class="section-title2 h1"><u>AC</u>HIEVEMENTS</h5>

  <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 " id="pills-tab" role="tablist" style="display:flex; justify-content: center; margin-top: 18px;padding-top: px; ">



    <li class="nav-item  active" role="presentation">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-Random" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 120%; ">Random</a>
    </li>


    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-web-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#website" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 120%; ">Web</a>
    </li>


    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contactu" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 120%; ">Graphic</a>
    </li>
  </ul>




  <!-- Album number 1 -->




  <div class="tab-content " id="pills-tabContent" style="display:flex; justify-content: center;text-align:center;margin-top: -23px;">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="pills-Random" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">

      <div class="slider">
        <figure class="slider_item" style="">
          <a href="images/Achievements/Randam/repo.png"><img class="slider_image" src="images/Achievements/Randam/repo.png"></a>
          <figcaption class="slider__caption" style="margin-top: 6px;">Git Hub Activities</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="slider_item" style="">
          <a href="images/Achievements/Randam/freelancing digiskills.png"><img class="slider_image" src="images/Achievements/Randam/freelancing digiskills.png"></a>
          <figcaption class="slider__caption" style="margin-top: 6px;">Freelancing Certificate</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="slider_item" style="">
          <a href="images/Achievements/Randam/Upwork.png"><img class="slider_image" src="images/Achievements/Randam/Upwork.png"></a>
          <figcaption class="slider__caption" style="margin-top: 6px;">Upwork</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="slider_item" style="">
          <a href="images/Achievements/Randam/youtuber.png"><img class="slider_image" src="images/Achievements/Randam/youtuber.png"></a>
          <figcaption class="slider__caption" style="margin-top: 6px;">Youtube Studio Certificate</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="slider_item" style="">
          <a href="images/Achievements/Randam/seo digiSkills.png"><img class="slider_image" src="images/Achievements/Randam/seo digiSkills.png"></a>
          <figcaption class="slider__caption" style="margin-top: 6px;">SEO Certificate</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="slider_item" style="">
          <a href="images/Achievements/Randam/StackOverFlow.png"><img class="slider_image" src="images/Achievements/Randam/StackOverFlow.png"></a>
          <figcaption class="slider__caption" style="margin-top: 6px;">StackOverFlow Rank</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="slider_item" style="">
          <a href="images/Achievements/Randam/comment.jpeg"><img class="slider_image" src="images/Achievements/Randam/comment.jpeg"></a>
          <figcaption class="slider__caption" style="margin-top: 6px;">Youtube Comment Response </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>


      <div class="slider__btn" style=" border-right: 2vmin solid rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.8);border-bottom: 2vmin solid rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.65);margin-top:-8%;"></div>

    </div>
  </div>

















  <div class="tab-content " id="pills-tabContent" style="display:flex; justify-content: center;text-align:center;margin-top: -23px;">
    <div class="tab-pane fade  " id="website" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-web">

      <div class="slider">

        <figure class="slider_item" style="">
          <a href="images/Achievements/Randam/seo digiSkills.png"><img class="slider_image" src="images/Achievements/Randam/seo digiSkills.png"></a>
          <figcaption class="slider__caption" style="margin-top: 6px;">SEO Certificate</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="slider_item" style="">
          <a href="images/Achievements/Randam/StackOverFlow.png"><img class="slider_image" src="images/Achievements/Randam/StackOverFlow.png"></a>
          <figcaption class="slider__caption" style="margin-top: 6px;">StackOverFlow Rank</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure class="slider_item" style="">
          <a href="images/Achievements/Randam/comment.jpeg"><img class="slider_image" src="images/Achievements/Randam/comment.jpeg"></a>
          <figcaption class="slider__caption" style="margin-top: 6px;">Youtube Comment Response </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>


      <div class="slider__btn" style=" border-right: 2vmin solid rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.8);border-bottom: 2vmin solid rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.65);margin-top:-8%;"></div>


    </div>





    <!-- 
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-web-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-web-tab">
    <b>shahmir</b>hi

</div> -->





    <div class="tab-pane fade " id="pills-contactu" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">

      DOG
    </div>


  </div>


  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- content -->



  <!-- ---------------------------          /Album                 ------------------------>



  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>






























  <!-----------------------    album    ---------------------------------->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var btn = $(".slider__btn");

      btn.on("click", function() {
        $(".slider__item").first().clone().appendTo(".slider");
        $(".slider__image").first().css({
          transform: "rotateX(-180deg)",
          opacity: 0
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(".slider__item").first().remove();
        }, 200);
      });
    });
  </script>

  <!-----------------------    /album    ---------------------------------->


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</HTML>
</BODY>
```

Comment: Random Tab is ok .i dont know why it also disturb over here

Comment: just to say this error : `</HTML> </BODY>` is wrong, do  `</BODY> </HTML>`  in this order

Comment: another one; don't multiply jQuery or bootstrap library , just one is enough for each

Comment: use https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator.html.en